# Unable to run cameras under Opencv 4.1.2 and MacOS Catalina

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, macos-catalina

I am unable to open a camera on the network using Catalina, Python 3.7 and OpenCV 4.1.2.

I am running an IP Webcam app on a phone that exposes an endpoint as: http://192.168.87.26:8080/video. The following command fails:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.87.26:8080/video')
```

and the error message is:

```
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "http://192.168.87.26:8080/video"
```

At the same time, a video mp4 file works well. I have added permissions in MacOS such that the default webcam also works.

I have tried with both the pip install opencv-python as well as built an opencv from source, but the error for the video stream does not go away.

FFMPEG is installed in the system. FFPLAY on this URL http://192.168.87.26:8080/video works very well.

```
$ brew info ffmpeg
ffmpeg: stable 4.2.1 (bottled), HEAD
Play, record, convert, and stream audio and video
https://ffmpeg.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_2 (287 files, 56.6MB) *
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging around, I was able to make it work. Looks like I had an old version of Intel OpenVINO around from Mojave days that was interfering with any local version of OpenCV that I would install.

During the exercise, I also figured that building OpenCV from scratch is far better than installing it from pip.